# Navigation bar now showing using Coordinator navigation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

To separate screen navigation logic from `UIViewController` followed this tutorial:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/71/how-to-use-the-coordinator-pattern-in-ios-apps

Everything set up correctly using `Coordinator` `protocol`, but the navigation bar not showing.

**Coordinator.swift**

```
protocol Coordinator {
    var childCoordinator: [Coordinator] {get set}
    var navigationController: UINavigationController {get set}

    func start()
}
```

**MainCoordinator.swift**

```
class MainCoordinator: Coordinator {
    var childCoordinator = [Coordinator]()

    var navigationController: UINavigationController

    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
    }
    func start() {
        let vc = ViewController.instantiate()
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
        navigationController.title = "Home"
        navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

    }
}
```

Full source code can be found on GitHub:
https://github.com/harshal-wani/CoordinatorNavigation

How to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Do we need to modify SceneDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `title` to `navigationController` instead of `ViewController` so you are not able to see the `title` on the `navigationBar` that exists. Set `title` as,

```
func start() {
    let vc = ViewController.instantiate()
    vc.title = "Home"
    navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
    navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true  // 4

}
```

Comment: Then you might have another issue where the viewController is not being created with the above code.

Comment: by removing SceneDelegate delegate methods from AppDelegate and key from info.plist it works

Comment: Yes, along fixing that you need to change as above.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative you can also modify the scene delegate as follows:

```
var window: UIWindow?
var coordinator: MainCoordinator?

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    let navController = UINavigationController()
    coordinator = MainCoordinator(navigationController: navController)
    coordinator?.start()

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = navController
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```